# Probability of Event Z given Multiple Events

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Is there a formula to find the probability of event $Z$ happening, given that other conditions (events $A,B...F$) is true? $A,B...F$ are independent of each other, but $Z$ is dependent on all other events.

Comment: $P(Z|A,B,...,F)=\frac{P(Z,A,B,...,F)}{P(A,B,...,F)}$?

Comment: are the independent ? otherwise certain ones force potentially 100%

Comment: @ShubhamJohri So, the probability of all events happening divided by the probability of only $A,B...F$ happening? Wouldn't that just be $P(Z)$?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Edited question.

Comment: https://youtube.com/watch?v=M8xlOm2wPAA

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I am confused.

Comment: about what ? they partially go over multiple events in a second video related to this at very least.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee  They don't go over multiple events at all.

Comment: @QuoteDave The formula I mentioned is a very basic conditional probability formula -- that is how conditional probability is defined. If the events $Z$ and $X=(A,B,...,F)$ are independent of each other, then the answer is certainly $P(Z)$, but in your example, as you state, this is not the case.